# How to link observer to methods from another block

Tags: event-observer, addtocart, magento-1

I have an observer and would like to get the selected custom options array.
The observer event is:

```
checkout_cart_product_add_after
```

I have found the two methods I require in:

```
app/design/frontend/MY-THEME/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```

Which are:

```
$_item = $this->getItem();
$_options = $this->getOptionList();
```

I just don't know how to link to them from an observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the code in Magento the observer is fired from `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::addProduct` with the following code

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after', array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));
```

The template you're referencing uses block `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer` so from there we can find out what the methods `getItem` and `getOptionList` do.

**getItem**

Get item returns the item that is set via `setItem` which accepts an instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item`. Since the events param `quote_item` is the result of an item added to the quote these match.

**getOptionList**

this method is the same as `getProductOptions`. This method has the following code

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_configuration');
return $helper->getCustomOptions($this->getItem());
```

So, to define your observer method

```
class [Namespace]_[Model]_Model_Observer
{
   function yourFunction($observer)
   {
      $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();

      $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_configuration');
      $optionList = $helper->getCustomOptions($item)

   }
}
```

et voilá, you're done

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Unfortunately, $optionlist is returning an empty array?? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try to do some debugging if possible. Is the item filled with the right quote item for example. I've used this code in a module before so it should work as far as I know

Comment: It works perfectly...would have found out sooner if the product I was testing actually had some custom options, doh! Many thanks!